# Add Shorter audio to video with loop with volume control of both audio and video and with only for a specific duration using FFMpeg

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-editing

Add Shorter audio to video with loop with volume control of both audio and video and with only for a specific duration ((i want to add audio and keep both audio and the videos sound in both cases))

I have two part of a problem

1) audio is 27 seconds long
2) Video is 2 mins 24 seconds long

a) I want to loop the audio and add it to the video
for example (add audio only) from 50 seconds to 1 min 30 seconds (not the whole video but still get the whole video as output )within the video , with the looped audio

b) create a clip of video from 50 seconds to 1 min 30 seconds (not whole video as output)within the video , with the looped audio

I have used follwing command from ffmpeg to add audio to video , which adds it the whole video, how can we
i) specify only a part of video to have the looped audio
ii) create a new clip for the selected duration with the looped audio

so far I Have been able to loop, and change volume of both audio and video and mix them with following command for whole video

```
"-y","-i",videofile, "-filter_complex",
                        "amovie=audiofile:loop=1000,asetpts=N/SR/TB,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];" +
                        "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=0.5[a2];" +
                        " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
                        "-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-shortest","-preset", "ultrafast", outputfile
```

I am stuck in managing time in both the cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
amovie=audiofile:loop=1000,asetpts=N/SR/TB,atrim=0:40,adelay=50000|50000,apad,aformat=...
```

The trim keeps first 40 seconds of the looped audio, the adelay shifts its start time to 50000 milliseconds i.e. 50 seconds.

Comment: your solution worked, but created an issue it created a video file which is 90 sec long, right from the start of the video ie 0 sec, and audio starting from 50 sec to 90 sec,what I want is two thing 1) create a file which would start from say 50 sec and ends at 90 sec (in all just 40 sec long)with audio of (40 sec) that we have and 2) create a file which is of  the original length(say 300sec) of the original video but have the audio from 50sec to 90sec part of the video, thanks for your help

Comment: For 1), add `-ss 50` after the filters. For 2), remove `-shortest`.

Comment: second part of my problem is solved, thanks, as regards to the first thing, I added `-ss 50`, but it created a new file which is 90 sec (50+40) , so i added `-t 40` just to get a 40 sec long video, but then no audio was added  can you help with that , again thanks

Comment: thanks Mulvya , your guidance was very helpful , i solved both issues I am sharing the code for others help aswell, again thanks

Comment: one more thing, @Mulvya, if a audio is a longer say 1 min and we want add just a part of the audio say from 18 sec to 35 sec  with loop to the audio how can that be done

Answer (score 0):

this is a code for 
adding a audio to video with
1) looping audio
2) change volume of both audio and video
3) create a new file of set duration only
4) create a file with original video duration and audio at a certain part of video

A) for new file of set duration only

```
"-y","-i",j,
                        "-filter_complex",
                        "amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB," +
                                "atrim=0:40,adelay=50000|50000,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];" +
                                "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=2.0[a2];" +
                                " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
                        "-ss","50", "-t","40","-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

the thing we do is add `"-ss","50", "-t","40"`

b) for a file with original video duration and audio at a certain part of video

```
"-y","-i",j,
                            "-filter_complex",
                            "amovie="+audio+":loop=999,asetpts=N/SR/TB," +
                                    "atrim=0:40,adelay=50000|50000,aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=1.5[a1];" +
                                    "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=fltp:sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo,volume=2.0[a2];" +
                                    " [a1][a2]amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3[out]",
                            "-ss","50", "-map","0:v","-map","[out]","-c:v","copy","-c:a","aac","-preset", "ultrafast", out
```

the thing we do is add `"-ss","50"`  **but dont add** "-t","40"`